# Get author meta only if filled out in WordPress, basic if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in which I have added a few extra fields for Author contact fields. Some people are going to use Google plus but some will not. I don't want to have an empty paragraph tag etc. I can't seem to figure out how to write an if statement that works. This is what I was working with. Thanks for your time.

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('google')) ?> { ?>

    <p><?php the_author_meta('google'); ?></p>

<?php }

    else {
            // do nothing

} endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('google')):  ?>

<p><?php the_author_meta('google'); ?></p>

<?php 

else: 
        // do nothing

 endif; ?>
```

Did you try this? Also, your code has the opening brace for 'if' without a php tag.

Comment: both of these answers seem to work. Can you tell me about the colon in the top there?

Comment: This is an alternate syntax to specify opening brace with a colon and the closing with endif.

Comment: Ah ha - ok. Well I didn't really learn much from that explanation, but it works - so answered it is! Thank you.

Comment: So if you notice the code there are no opening and closing braces for if and else. They are replaced by colons. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this - and put a class of some sort on there to ensure it's not showing up in the spots where it's not filled in - a border or something?

```
<?php if (get_the_author_meta('google')) { ?>

    <p class="error"><?php the_author_meta('google') ?></p>

<?php }

else {

    // do nothing

} ?>
```

This seems to work. Maybe it's the endif ?